# Inverted Python Dictionary JSON

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create an inverted dictionary in Python

```
import json

def readfile():
    with open('/home/krishna/Desktop/data/synonyms.json', 'r') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        j = json.loads(read_data)
        inverted_dict = dict([v,k] for k,v in j.items())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    readfile()
```

Synonyms text file has :

```
{
viral fever: [
"fever",
"viral fever"
],
sickness: [
"acute sickness",
"typhoid"
],..
}
```

The error i am facing is:

```
File "/home/krishna/Desktop/Scripts/jsonparse.py", line 7, in readfile
inverted_dict = dict([v,k] for k,v in j.items())
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My Expected Output a dictionary of

```
fever: viral fever
viral fever: viral fever
acute sickness: sickness
typhoid: sickness
```

Comment: And what would the expected output be? Is `fever` a key for `'viral fever'` or is `('fever', 'viral fever')` the key?

Comment: You can't have a list as a dict key.

Answer (score 2):

Your values are lists; you need to loop over the elements for each value explicitly to make those separate keys:

```
dict((i, k) for k, v in j.items() for i in v)
```

If you are using Python 2.7 or 3, you can use a dictionary comprehension here too:

```
{i: k for k, v in j.items() for i in v}
```

This *can* lead to duplicate entries, only the last one will 'stick'. If there are repeated values across multiple values (so `fever` being in the list for both `sickness` and `viral fever`, you'd need to build a dictionary with `set` or `list` values instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in j.items():
    for i in v:
        result[i].add(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list `["fever", "viral fever"]` is not a valid key for a dict because it's mutable.

You might want either:

- use the strings `"fever"` and `"viral fever"` as separate keys that refer to the same value,
- use a tuple `("fever", "viral fever")` or a frozenset `frozenset(["fever", "viral fever"])` instead of a list as dict keys. (Sets have no order.)